# Content disappearing after zooming in too much

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a headbar
the problem is that when I zoom in after a while the list of buttons disappears from screen.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="headbar">
        <img src="http://opensource.org/files/osi_symbol.png" style="height:100%;float:left;"/>

            <ul>            

                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
            </ul>

    </div>          

    <div id="bodypage">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">   
    </div>  
</body>
```

CSS code and how the page looks:http://codepen.io/overclock351/pen/qdyoBq

Comment: How many levels of zoom do you want to accommodate? I can zoom 5 times or more without a problem.

Comment: Answer the question, please. There's a reasonable limit to how much any website can be expected to zoom.

Comment: I have never enstablished any limit: i got problems after reaching 240% of zoom (on firefox)

Comment: Can't reproduce it within sane levels of zooming. Also, perhaps you should start looking into SVGs instead of using PNGs for web graphic elements as they are way more adaptive to resizing without any distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@isherwood was correct.

By removing the `overflow:hidden` from the `#headbar` your buttons will show when zoomed in. I got to 500% in Chrome with no problems.

Comment: yeah but the buttons will go under the headbar

Comment: At 300% the buttons are to the right and the image is to the left. Why does it matter? Who will zoom in past 300% anyway?... You could add some media queries to re-size the image after a certain point.

Comment: On firefox 300% is the maximum zoom and the buttons are going down the logo and the header bar. Could be a monitor issue(i got a tiny monitor).

Comment: Have you got some tutorials for those queries please?

Comment: Yeah: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries | 

https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/